# Image placeholder in Xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am  using the `xaringan` library from Yihui in `R` to create a custom template for a presentation.

Part of this is creating custom `body` slides as pictured below.

[image]

I then use custom `CSS` for the headers and body:

```
  .body-yellow > h2 {
      font-size: 42px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-left: 
}
```

And then just type in `rmarkdown` something like:

```
---
class: body-yellow

# Hello

## world

Hello world
```

This then populates the slide.

My question is, is there a way to create a placeholder for the image shown in the template above that I could adjust in the rmarkdown code itself?

I am imagining code like:

```
---
class: body-yellow
background-images: url(./img/my_new_custom_image.png)

# Hello

## world

Hello world
```

And the relevant adjustment in `CSS`:

```
 .body-yellow > image {
    background-images: PLACEHOLDER
    position:right
    }
```

Which will change the image as follows:

[image]

Excuse my [CSS](https://i.gifer.com/77MD.mp4) ignorance, but I am only starting to dabble in this area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a global background image for the `body-yellow` class, and override it with the `background-image` attribute on a particular slide. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      ratio: "16:9"
---

class: body-yellow

```{css, echo=FALSE}
 .body-yellow > h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.body-yellow {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSrg8t.png);
  background-size: contain;
}
```


## Default background

---
class: body-yellow
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1C2Bt.png)

## A custom background
````

[image: Use a custom background to override the default]